# Insert a lot of products opencart script

Tags: python, csv, module, mysql-python, opencart

I have a script in python in which I have all my products, descriptions , images, etc. Now I want to insert all this information in my Opencart theme. I try to find out how to save it all of this in the MySQl database. I know I have to use MySQLdb for python but I don't know in which place I have to save de name, the direction of the image, the image, the size....

I know that there is import/export modules. Maybe I have to install one of those modules and save my information in a csv file and then import it.

Which would be the most quick method to insert all of this? Is there any other method? Because the modules are quite expensive.

Thank you so much!!

Answer (score 2):

Your best option in my opinion is to use an Import/Export tool (there are free ones available like the [excel tool by JNeuhoff](http://www.opencart.com/index.php?route=extension/extension/info&extension_id=17)). It's fairly easy to use once you figure out what you are doing. The best thing to do is to clear all the default data that comes with an install, create a couple of products, categories etc and export via the import/export tool, see how it comprises the data, then start developing a script to generate the fields from your current store items to fill it. I would also recommend installing [vQmod](http://vqmod.com/) too so that you can install it without making core changes to your admin files